# How to migrate from ActiveRecord's Serialize Array to Postgres Array datatype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Rails 4 supports [postgres' array data type](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/), and we want to start taking advantage of the array types in postgres , how can I migrate an existing [ActiveRecord serialized array](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) field to the new data type?

Answer (score 2):

`serialize` stores things inside the database as YAML documents in a text column. YAML isn't the easiest format to work with inside a database so the most straightforward approach would be to:

1. Add an array column to hold the arrays.
2. Loop through each record in Rails, let ActiveRecord unserialize the YAML, copy the Ruby arrays from the `serialize` column to the real array column from **1**.
3. Remove the `serialize` declaration from your model.
4. Drop the old column that `serialize` used.
5. Rename the column from **1**.
6. Set the newly renamed column to `NOT NULL` if desired.

You could parse the YAML inside the database using [regex](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) and [string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) functions but that would depend on what sorts of things you're storing in your YAML.